# Google Compute Engine API : can't create instance from machine image

Tags: node.js, sdk, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a new GCE instance with the Google API NodeJS SDK from a machine image that I already created before.
I'm using the JSON template given by the GCP UI console.

But the SDK return an error about the disk ressource when i'm calling the create function :
`Error: Invalid value for field 'resource.disks': ''. No disks are specified.`

The JSON template contain only `disks : []` indeed, but the disk is supposed to be created from the machine image and I can't create new disk using the "sourceDisk" object (tried "SourceImage"  but it doesn't work using the machine image url)

I can't find lot of information about machine images in the SDK from the documentation. Is there something i've missed ?  ​

My config.json

```json
{
   ​"kind": "compute#instance",
   ​"name": "$vmName",
   ​"project": "xxxx",
   ​"zone": "projects/xxx/zones/europe-west4-a",
   ​"minCpuPlatform": "Automatic",
   ​"machineType": "projects/xxxx/zones/europe-west4-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-2",
   ​"displayDevice": {
       ​"enableDisplay": false
   ​},
   ​"metadata": {
       ​"kind": "compute#metadata"
   ​},
   ​"disks": [],
   ​"canIpForward": false,
   ​"description": "",
   ​"labels": {},
   ​"scheduling": {
       ​"preemptible": false,
       ​"onHostMaintenance": "MIGRATE",
       ​"automaticRestart": true,
       ​"nodeAffinities": []
   ​},
   ​"deletionProtection": false,
   ​"reservationAffinity": {
       ​"consumeReservationType": "ANY_RESERVATION"
   ​},
   ​"sourceMachineImage": "projects/xxxx/global/machineImages/vm-snap-test-damien",
   ​"shieldedInstanceConfig": {
       ​"enableSecureBoot": false,
       ​"enableVtpm": true,
       ​"enableIntegrityMonitoring": true
   ​},
   ​"confidentialInstanceConfig": {
       ​"enableConfidentialCompute": false
   ​}
}
```

Comment: Include enough information to clearly see the API you are calling with the parameters, body, etc. Include details on the machine image.

Comment: Awesome that you found your own answer! Consider moving your answer from the question, down into an answer and marking it accepted. Stack Overflow encourages answering your own questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer  And this helps people see that the question is answered when searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

The MachineInstance API in GCE is for some functions still in **beta**.
The Google NodeJS API use by default the v1 endpoint.
To change it, simply change the `baseURL` in the resource object of Google. For my case it's

```js
var Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute()
compute.baseUrl = 'https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta' //Using Beta commands
```

This will enable the beta commands and allow you to launch these without error.